# jQuery Load, prevent from happening twice?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery load to load php pages into my content area.

I have noticed some screwy behavior if the user repeatedly clicks on the navigation menu items abusively.

Right now my code is as simple as hiding the content pane, loading the new page, then fading in:

```
 $("#homeLink").click(function(){
    $("#contentPane").hide();
    $("#contentPane").load("welcome.php");
    $("#contentPane").fadeIn();
 });
```

Problematic behavior: new link is clicked, pane fades in with the previous page (then updates to the new page)

I tried using `$.ajax({async:false});`, but this all persisted. At this point, I am considering re-writing my navigation system to vary includes based off of url parameters, unless some insight can be provided as to how I can stop it from queuing a second load call until the first is complete?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**"complete"**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) callback. It is executed when the request completes.

```
$("#homeLink").click(function() {
    var pane = $("#contentPane");

    pane.hide();
    pane.load("welcome.php", function() {
        pane.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah the success function! Tested, works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could chain your methods:

```
 $("#homeLink").click(function(){
    $("#contentPane").hide().load('welcome.php', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The load method can take two extra parameters: A set of query string key/value pairs, and a callback function which will be executed when the load method finishes, no matter if it succeeds or fails. Here is an example where we use the callback function to inform about the result. Normally, you would likely only show a message if the method fails, but to illustrate how it works, we do it if the method fails as well. I make sure that it fails for the example, by requesting a file which doesn't exist:

```
<div id="divTestArea3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
        $("#divTestArea3").load("no-content.html", function(responseText, statusText, xhr)
        {
                if(statusText == "success")
                        alert("Successfully loaded the content!");
                if(statusText == "error")
                        alert("An error occurred: " + xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText);
        });
});
</script>
```

As you can see, the callback function specifies 3 parameters, which jQuery will fill in for you. The first parameter will contain the resulting content if the call succeeds. The second parameter is a string which specifies the status of the call, e.g. "success" or "error". You can use it to see if the call was successful or not. The third parameter is the XMLHttpRequest object used to perform the AJAX call. It will contain properties which you can use to see what went wrong and many other things.
In your case it is better to use a callback to load the page when the request completes.